# Accept external REST calls from SpringBootTest context and verify the call

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, integration-testing, junit5

I am writing Spring Boot Integration test. For this, we boot up the empty application (context) and call multiple services as part of test.

One of the requirements is to call the external REST endpoint with payload that contains an URL to notify (call back) and that service, after some business logic, calls the URL received in the payload.

From the test, I can call the REST endpoint, which is external service. But I want to be able to test the call back from that service for the given URL. URL can be random.

Can I do with `MockClientServer`? OR `MockRestServiceServer` Or some other day to test this?

Essentially, I want the test to be able to get an external call and verify it.

Comment: I'm not aware that either the `MockRestServiceServer` or `WireMock` has such a feature. Why not simulate the callback yourself inside your test? Use the `WebTestClient` or `TestRestTemplate` to call your application after you called the external system.

Answer (score 0):

After trying out a couple things, `WireMock` actually does what I wanted. It takes the rest call from outside application(s). Very useful for testing.